# Validate TextBox In JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i need a validate textbox which is accepted like this $250.00 here is '$' will accepted only one time and then never accepted '$' as well as '.'(dot).

Comment: have your tried any thing ??

Comment: Regex is your friend. http://www.regular-expressions.info

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [masked input](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) for example
your mask would be

```
$('#input').mask('$9?.99');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
var x = document.getElementById('your-text-box').value;

if(x.match(/^\$[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/) == null) {
   // invalid
}
else {
   // valid
}
```

The regex `/^\$[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/` will *match* any string meeting the following constraints

- Should start with a `$`
- Should have `1 or more numbers` after the `$`
- Should have a `.` after the first set of numbers
- Should end with `1 or more numbers` after the `.`

Answer (score 0):

Is jquery an option?

Here is a jquery solution. First of all I wouldn't validate expecting user to put '$'. I would put that outside the form and just allow people to enter the amount. That's weird, but I guess I don't really have the context on what you are doing. See [Jquery validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation):

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      digits: true
    }
 }
});
```

This is using [digits](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/digits) to allow only numbers. Otherwise if you really need $ in there you need to create a [custom validation rule](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- wherever your jquery file is -->     
<script src="../../jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="cost"><input type="button" id="check" value="Check!"> 
<script>

// jquery solution

 $(document).ready( function (){
    $('#check').click( function (){
            var cost = $('#cost').val();
            var patt=/^(\$)?\d+(\.\d+)?$/;
            var result=patt.test(cost);
            alert(result);
            });

 });

 </script>
```

Of course you can use pure java script as well to reduce the dependency

```
<input type="text" id="cost">
<input type="button" id="check" value="Check!" onClick="check();"> 
<script>

//  Pure Javascript Solution 

var check = function (){
    var cost = document.getElementById('cost').value;
    var patt=/^(\$)?\d+(\.\d+)?$/;
    var result=patt.test(cost);
    alert(result);

}
</script>
```